# Twig_Error_Syntax :cannot extend from a block

Tags: twig, syntax-error, extends, symfony4

when  I try  to  extends  in  twig  I  have  this error  I did not understand it .
Is  there  any one  know what  is  mean ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmhTV.png)ean

Answer (score 1):

Do you have that `{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}` inside a `block`? I.e. something like this:

```
{% block myBlock %}

... code ...

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

... code ...

{% endblock %}
```

Because that would throw a `Twig_Error_Syntax` exception with the message "Cannot extend from a block." This can be seen in Twig's source code: [`Extends.php`, line 27](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.4.4/lib/Twig/TokenParser/Extends.php#L27) and [`parent_in_a_block.test`](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.4.4/test/Twig/Tests/Fixtures/tags/inheritance/parent_in_a_block.test).